# Providng maven build output as a plugin dependency

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I have a custom factory implementation I'd like to provide to wro4j maven plugin through a string parameter. Trouble is the factory is built in the same project as the plugin so the plugin doesn't get passed the output from the build and i get a nice ClassNotFoundException.

I'm aware that there is an annotation I could attach to the wro4j mojo to make it aware of the build output but that would require patching and building wro4j from source which doesn't sound smart. I'm also not keen on creating a whole different artifact just to contain my 5 line factory implementation. It feels like there should be an easier way, so the question is

**Is there a way to pass build artifacts to a plugin in the same pom WITHOUT editing the mojo?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have to guess what the issue is without an actual plugin configuration. But generally, if you need to add dependency (or class) to some of your plugins, you will have to wrap that class into its own artifact, i.e. move it into a separate project.

Fundamentally Maven does plugin dependency resolution before kicking in the rest of build cycle, so your classes may haven't been compiled yet at that point.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I suspected but didn't hurt to ask. I turned the project into a multi-module build and used project a as a dependency to the plugin so at least I can do the whole operation with one command. Definitely seems like overkill to use a compiled language for this job...

Answer (score 1):

Try instructing the wro4j plugin to execute in the `process-classes` phase instead of the `compile` phase, when your factory class is compiled (`process-classes` happens right after `compile`):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>wro4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${wro4j.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <wroManagerFactory>...</wroManagerFactory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```